# typo3 - undo "setSessionCookie"

Tags: cookies, authentication, typo3, extbase

I am trying to implement a "stay logged in" functionality in typo3 (using extbase), so when the user checks a checkbox named "rememberMe", the session cookie is set:

```
    //rememberMe ?
    if($user->getRememberMe() == 1){
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);
        $setSessionCookieMethod = $reflection->getMethod('setSessionCookie');
        $setSessionCookieMethod->setAccessible(TRUE);
        $setSessionCookieMethod->invoke($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);
    }else{
        // ??? 
    }
```

This works fine, but my problem is - what do I do when the user no longer wants to be permanently logged in? If the checkbox is unchecked - how do I undo the session cookie without logging out the user? Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal behavior is to delete the the permanently-logged-in-information at the moment the user logs out. IMHO this is the most logical and behavior.

Comment: I agree. But the customer wants a different behaviour, unfortunately. I know it's stupid but is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?